# Error: Cannot find module 'utils'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a file `main.js` using Casper.js via `casperjs main.js`, which uses a module `./lib/myUtils.js`, which in turn uses

```
var utils = require('utils')
```

But running `casperjs main.js` throws the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'utils'

  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
  /Users/username/casper-test/lib/myUtils.js:2
  /Users/username/casper-test/lib/myUtils.js:63
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myUtils.loadCookies()')
  /Users/username/casper-test/main.js:104
```

The functions being imported have `"use strict";` in their first line.

However putting the code from `myUtils.js` directly into `main.js` avoids the error. Why is this?

Comment: Are you importing the file correctly in your script tag ?

Comment: @ODelibalta I guess so... `var utils = require('utils')`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to insert `var require = patchRequire(require);` at the beginning of your file ( `myUtils.js` ).